# Meaning of "break with one's bread" in "Revenge now I sought, to break with my bread"

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is coming from the lyrics of "Am I Evil".
I'm puzzled about the meaning of "break with my bread" in this context.
Does it mean "to break my bread with revenge" in a figurative sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems to be from lyrics by a song by Diamond Head. There is an idiom in English, "to break bread with", which means to eat with someone.

[Merriam-Webster "break"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20bread)

> break bread
> : to dine together

The lyrics of that song seem to try to extend that idiom, trying to mean, somehow, that "I will eat revenge along with my bread", or maybe "eat in the company of Revenge". The rest of the lyric is basically nonsensical, so there is probably not much real meaning there.

Answer (score 1):

"To break bread with someone" means "To eat with someone", which represents that the two people who are having a meal together, are actually "friends" or "allies". They wouldn't be eating together if they were enemies. And this phrase from Metallica is a beautiful example of where this idiom can be used. He simply wants to take revenge, but he's delivering his message in a way that shows how he actually feels. He wants to take revenge so bad that he sort of thinks of revenge as his friend.